# Could we characterize elements in the second dual by the character space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two **semisimple** commutative Banach algebras.  Assume  that $A\mathbin{\tilde\otimes} B$ is a Banach algebra obtained by completing $A\otimes B$  with  respect to  a cross  norm not less than  the injective norm. It is well known that the character space of $A\mathbin{\tilde\otimes} B$, $\Delta(A\mathbin{\tilde\otimes} B)$, becomes $\Delta(A)\times\Delta(B)$. Let $\mathbb a$ be an element in the second dual $(A\mathbin{\tilde\otimes} B)^{**}$ not in $A\mathbin{\tilde\otimes} B$. Is it true that there exists character $\phi\in\Delta(A)$ or $\psi\in\Delta(B)$  such that, $(\phi\otimes\mathrm{id})^{**}(\mathbb a)\notin B$ or $(\mathrm{id}\otimes\psi)^{**}(\mathbb a)\notin A$? Here $\mathrm{id}$ denotes the identity map on $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Something is confusing me about the notation. $\phi\otimes {\rm id}$ looks like it should be applied to elements of $A \tilde{\otimes} B$. How are you defining $(\phi\otimes {\rm id})({\bf x})$ when ${\bf x}$ is an element of $(A\tilde{\otimes} B)^{**}$?

Comment: Thinking further: do you mean something like the following? Given ${\bf x} \in (A\tilde{\otimes} B)^{**}$, we know that $\langle {\bf x}, \alpha\otimes\beta\rangle$ makes sense for $\alpha\in A^{*}$ and $\beta\in B^*$; we then define $(\alpha\otimes {\rm id})({\bf x})$ to be the element of $B^{**}$ which maps $\beta\in B^*$ to the complex number $\langle {\bf x}, \alpha\otimes\beta\rangle$. Is that correct?

Comment: Finally: I think your question will have a trivial negative answer if $\Delta(A)$ and $\Delta(B)$ are empty. Did you really mean to include this possibility?

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for your comments, I tried to clear up the confusion, I hope it happened.